# SessionNotFoundException opening a new browser with Selenium + geb

Tags: selenium, groovy, geb

I want to close and start a new browser/window in my test, so I tried:

```
browser.close();
driver.close();
driver = new ChromeDriver()
```

output:

```
org.openqa.selenium.remote.SessionNotFoundException at myTest.groovy:169
```

Linea 169 is:

```
driver.close();
```

Everything I put just after the browser.close() will output the same error.

I've also tried storing cookies and config:
Set allCookies = driver.manage().getCookies();

```
for(Cookie cookie : allCookies)
            {
                driver.manage().addCookie(cookie);
                System.out.println(cookie);
            }
            browser.driver = browser.config.driver */
```

My GebConfig.groovy:

```
driver = {
    System.setProperty('webdriver.chrome.driver', '.\\drivers\\ChromeDriver\\chromedriver.exe')
    newDriver = new ChromeDriver()
    newDriver.manage().window().maximize();

    autoClearCookies = false
    return newDriver;

    }
```

All I need to do is close current window, open a new one and start with another test.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Note that `browser.close()` calls `driver.close()` so you are essentially calling `driver.close()` two times.

What you really need is to clear the driver cache (I'm assuming that you are using the cache as it is the default) by calling `CachingDriverFactory.clearCacheAndQuitDriver()` and then to create a new instance of `Browser` using `browser = new Browser()` which will create a new instance of `Driver`.